# how to find size of the feeds at JSTL

Tags: jsp, rss, jstl

I need to find the size of the JSTL and write it to end="size of the feed " at the following code. Could you please help me how to find the size of the feed?

Regards
Altaico

```
<x:forEach begin="0" end="4" var="story"
           select="$doc/rss/channel/item" varStatus="status">
//end = "size of the rss"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't specify `start` and `end` and every item will be iterated.

```
<x:forEach var="story"
    select="$doc/rss/channel/item" varStatus="status">
```